# tableView tag wrong after moveRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, tags, tableview

I have a view with 7 tableViews representing the 7 days of the week. Each tableView is initialized with tag from 0 to 6. I made a longPressure recognizer in the cells to get access to the right tableView:

```
- (IBAction)longPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    self.clickedPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];

    // get most down subView user clicked
    UIView *clickedSubView = [self.view hitTest:self.clickedPoint withEvent:nil];

    if( [clickedSubView.superview isKindOfClass:[customCell class]] ) {

        // get selected tableView
        UITableView *selectedTableView = (UITableView*)clickedSubView.superview.superview;

        NSLog(@"Selected tag: %d", selectedTableView.tag);
    }
}
```

When I press the cell the tags are shown correctly. The problem is when I move row inside of  a tableView. When I do moveRowAtIndexPath: in a tableView and longPress, the tag of the tableView where I made the moveRow always gets the tag of the last longPress of another tableView.

Example:

I moveRow in table with tag 2. Then just longPress table with tag 5. Then go back to longPress table of tag 2 but this time will log tag = 5 (the one immediately before). If longPress table with tag 1, then go back to longPress "table of tag 2"(suppose to be) again and it logs tag 1 where it should be tag 2.

I have read that beginUpdates makes lose the tag and that is necessary to reload. So I have tried this:

```
// reload the tableView after moveRowAtIndexPath method
selectedTableView reloadData];

// also tried refresh the view that contains all the tableViews
[[self getWeekView] setNeedsDisplay];

// and also tried to set the tag again after moveRowAtIndexPath method
selectedTableView.tag = index;
```

Nothing works. I also suspected if something was happening to clickedSubView and if I was getting the the right hitTest view but I tested it with colored borders and it gets the right view, only with the wrong tag after the moveRowAtIndexPath method.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using custom cell for tableviews, i suppose you are using then just add one label on custom cell or if you dont want to show that tag then keep it hidden.

When you will load tableview cells with data in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method that time only you set tag label so you wont get this problem of tag.

Comment: @Aniket Kote Can you tell me, when i should set value on label of custom cell? If i move row from index position 4 to 0, then tag will change upto index 4 row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the table view that has been long-pressed on, add the gesture recognizer to the table view itself (not the cells). Then you can just request the view with `sender.view`. You can still do your hit detection to get the view that was actually long-pressed if you need it.

Comment: I should also mention that I applied the long press to the cell because I use it for other stuff. Sorry for not mention that before

Comment: What 'other stuff'? It's easier to go from the table to the cell than the other way around.

Comment: The longPress is applied to a mainView because it's content changes but has some common content. I have this mainViewController where it gets the longPress method recognizer that works with different content . So that's why I do the "transformation" of the recognized longPressed view depending on the content at the moment